# Optimizing Routes between Agenda Appointments with Fixed Times

Tags: javascript, algorithm, optimization

For a personal project I am looking for a way/algorithm to optimize agendas that contain appointments at specific times, containing pauses. But I can't seem to crack this problem. I think the best way to make it clear is to give an example:

#### Example

I have 10 different agendas for 10 different salesmen, each containing appointments or pauses (i.e., empty slots) at times from 9:00, 10:00, 11:00...17:00. This makes me end up with a list of places per time slot I need to have a salesman at (varying anywhere from 0 to 10 due to possible pauses).

My question is: what implementation can I use to compose 10 agendas from the above data in the most time- and cost-efficient way possible? This preferably with a way to set a maximum amount of appointments per agenda, and keeping in mind a maximum travel time between appointments.

I'm doing this in JavaScript, but examples in other languages are of course appreciated.

Comment: The question is way too broad to even give/ provide an example... and not even a google search.

Comment: Well, what you have here is an optimization problem and there are many many approaches for solving those. However, I even don't understand what you are really trying to do. For example you mention travel times but you don't say how they are determined.

Answer (score 1):

This is a scheduling problem, check out [Job shop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_shop_scheduling) and [Nurse scheduling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nurse_scheduling_problem). It's NP-hard so you won't find the optimal solution other than in very limited or specific cases. But there exists algoritms that can give good results fast, here's one to get you started.

Assume you have an array of meetings `M` with `n` elements. A meeting has a start time and a stop time. (we ignore pauses in the meetings, you're not going to fit another meeting there) Further assume you have an array of salesmen schedules `S` with `k` elements.

```
sort M according to the END TIME of each meeting
let FinalTime be the time when the last meeting starts
for each salesman in S
    let t be the first available timeslot on the salesman's schedule
    while t <= FinalTime
        assign the unassigned meeting with start time >= t that finishes first to the salesman
        set t to the end time of the assigned meeting
```

By picking the meeting that ends first, we will favour shorter meetings before longer, and be able to fit more meetings into our schedule. This assumes there are more meetings than can fit in the schedules combined.